# variable error in bash

Tags: shell-script, python

I am writing my first code in bash. I am stuck from 2 hours. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i l=0
declare -i d=0
declare -i s1=0
declare -i s2=0
declare -i t=0
declare -i o=0
declare -i p=0
for i in demo_room/subject_1/?*
do
    if [ "${i:0:1}" = "l" ];
    then
            ((l++));
            echo "l=$l"
            python motempl_n.py $i $l

    elif [  "${i:0:1}" = "d" ];
    then
            ((d++));
            echo "d=$d"
            python motempl_n.py $i $d

    elif [  "${i:0:1}" = "o" ];
    then
            o=$((o+1));
            echo "o=$o"
            python motempl_n.py $i $o

    elif [ "${i:0:1}" = "p" ];
    then
            p=$((p+1));
            python motempl_n.py $i $p

    elif [  "${i:0:1}" = "t" ];
    then
            t=$((t+1));
            python motempl_n.py $i $t

    elif [  "${i:0:7}" = "slide_1" ];
    then
            s1=$((s1+1));
            python motempl_n.py $i $s1

    #elif [  "${i:0:7}" == 'slide_2' ]
    else
            s2=$((s2+1));
            python motempl_n.py $i $s2

   fi 
done
```

So I am having a folder `demo_room/subject_1`. In this folder I have 140 avi videos their names are:

20 videos have name: `dislike_01` to `dislike_20`

20 videos have name: `like_01` to `like_20`

20 videos have name: `ok_01` to `ok_20`

20 videos have name: `point_01` to `point_20`

20 videos have name: `slide_1_01` to `slide_1_20`

20 videos have name: `slide_2_01` to `slide_2_20`

20 videos have name: `take_a_picture_01` to `take_a_picture_1_20`

What I want to do is first find the class of the input video then give its occurrence as input to python file. First 20 videos of `subject_1` folder are `dislike` one so this code works fine but the 21st video is `like_01` but the parameter it passes to the python code is 21.

But it should be 1 because this is first video of like class in the for loop. And each time it prints 
value of `$d`. It means each time it goes in 2nd `if condition`. In the python code I can verify that the name of the video is `like_01` but second value passed is `21`. Why? This happens for all the 140 videos.

Comment: You should also quote your variables and remove the unnecessary `;`'s (all of them)

Comment: Your first bash script? Wow, you've already doing great!

Comment: The `echo` inside `[ ... ]` must be a typo, right? Also, you're inconsistent in how you increment your counters.

Comment: @Kusalananda that was typo fixed it. My first approach was using echo, but I got error `[ too many arguments`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `$i` will contain the full path (`demo_room/subject_1/file`), so will always start with `d`.

You could do something like:

```
case "${i##*/}" in
  (d*) ...;;
  (l*) ...;;
  (slide1_*) ...;;
  ...
esac
```

Where `${i##*/}` is `$i` with the leading part matching `*/` removed.

Also beware that parameter expansions need to be quoted in sh/bash:

```
python motempl_n.py "$i" "$s2"
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, I made some changed like passing ${i##*/} instead of $i in each case and also in my python file changed input video location.

Answer (score 7):

While your code is well written, there's a lot of duplication. Here's a more condensed version:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A count
for file in demo_room/subject_1/*; do
    base=${file##*/}
    case $base in
        slide_[12]*) key=${base:0:7};;
        [ldopt]*)    key=${base:0:1};;
        *)           ;; # other types ignored
    esac
    (( count[$key]++ ))
    echo "$key=${count[$key]}"
    python motempl_n.py "$file" "${count[$key]}"
done
```

I'm using an associative array instead of distinct integer variables, but fortunately bash arithmetic handles `(( an_unset_variable++ ))` gracefully and assigns "1" to the variable.

Note that the `?` in your `?*` was redundant as file names always contain at least one character, so there's no file that `*` (0 or more characters) would match and `?*` (1 or more characters) wouldn't.

Comment: That was for directory like . and..

Comment: `*` will not match dot-files unless you `shopt -s dotglob` or set `GLOBIGNORE` to certain values.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$i` variable always start with a `d`: `demo_room … …`
You need to extract the file name. And since we are extracting, we may as well extract both the name and the number of the file.

Thus, a shorter version of your script could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -Ai count

for i in ./demo_room/subject_1/?*; do
    j=${i##*/} ; name=${j%_*} ; number=${j##*_}
    ((count[$name]++))
    echo \
           python motempl_n.py "$i" "${count[$name]}"
done

echo "List of keys: " "${!count[@]}"
```

This script use only one array variable `count`, the list of (automatically) keys used (from `$name`) is printed at the end of the script.

Comment out the `echo \` line once you like how the script works to actually execute the commands.

Comment: Will $name and $number work for the files `slide_1_xx`?And also passing $j instead of $i will be more helpful because I just need file name inside the python file and not path because that I added manually.

Comment: At least: Did you try the script? … *work for the files slide_1_xx?* It did when I tested it. … *$i will be more helpful* Then, use it, no problem.

Comment: well I didn't try it but had doubt so asked it.But problem is solved thanks

Comment: @Debian_yadav If you do not try and learn: It is your loss, not mine. have a nice day.